# THREE.JS : object appears after zoom

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an issue on THREE.JS, I add a 3D text on my scene with that :

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( '3rdparty/three.js/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',function ( font ) {
   var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xff0000});
   var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello World!', {font: font});
   var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeom, material );
   var bBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(_object);
   textMesh.position.set((bBox.max.x - bBox.min.x) / 2 + 
   bBox.min.x,bBox.max.y + 10,(bBox.max.z - bBox.min.z) / 2 + bBox.min.z);
   scene.add(textMesh);
});
```

But the object appears only if I zoom on my scene text appears and same I can unzoom object stay visible.

[After text add, no text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pm9X.png)

[After zoom, text appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3kFq.png)

[After unzoom text still here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bbmn.png)

Here camera configuration (so it's not far camera paremeters issue) :

```
new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,SCREEN_WIDTH/SCREEN_HEIGHT,0.1,99999999);
```

How can I force text appears immediatly after add ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render your scene again after you adding your text by calling `render.render(scene, camera);`

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('3rdparty/three.js/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000
  });
  var textGeom = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello World!', {
    font: font
  });
  var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeom, material);
  var bBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(_object);
  textMesh.position.set((bBox.max.x - bBox.min.x) / 2 +
    bBox.min.x, bBox.max.y + 10, (bBox.max.z - bBox.min.z) / 2 + bBox.min.z);
  scene.add(textMesh);
  render.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Comment: Thank for your response, I find why I load obj and mtl from sweethome3d and after that I when I call render I get : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined"